# Google Sheets PHP API - Trouble with adding multiple tabs

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm having a heck of a time getting the PHP library for Google Sheets to let me create a Spreadsheet with multiple tabs (sheets). Snippet truncated for simplicity

```
use Google\Service\Exception as ServiceException;
use Google\Service\Sheets;
use Google\Service\Sheets\AddSheetRequest;
use Google\Service\Sheets\BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest;
use Google\Service\Sheets\BatchUpdateValuesRequest;
use Google\Service\Sheets\SheetProperties;
use Google\Service\Sheets\Spreadsheet;
    
function addTabs($sheetId, array $tabNames) {
    $requests = [];

    foreach ($tabNames as $index => $tabName) {
        $request = new AddSheetRequest();
        $props = new SheetProperties();
        $props->setTitle($tabName);
        $props->setIndex($index);
        $request->setProperties($props);
        $requests[] = $request;
    }

    $batchRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    $batchRequest->setRequests($requests);

    try {
        $this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($sheetId, $batchRequest);
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}

addTabs($id, ['A', 'B', 'C']);
```

Getting these errors.

```
    Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "properties" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.
    Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "properties" at 'requests[1]': Cannot find field.
    Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "properties" at 'requests[2]': Cannot find field.
```

I can't tell what's wrong here, as this seems to match the spec defined in the documentation
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddSheetRequest

Another tack I've tried is generating all tabs at once in the initial Spreadsheet creation request:

```
function createSheet()
{
    $sheetProps = [
        'properties' => [
            'title' => 'Test',
        ],
        'sheets' => [],
    ];
    $sheetRequest = new Spreadsheet($sheetProps);
    $sheet1 = [
        'properties' => [
            'title' => 'Tab 1',
        ],
        'data' => [
            'rowData' => [
                ['values' => [['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 1]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 2]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 3]]]],
                ['values' => [['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 4]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 5]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 6]]]],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $sheet2 = [
        'properties' => [
            'title' => 'Tab 2',
        ],
        'data' => [
            'rowData' => [
                ['values' => [['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 1]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 2]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 3]]]],
                ['values' => [['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 4]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 5]], ['userEnteredValue' => ['numberValue' => 6]]]],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $sheetRequest = new Spreadsheet([
        'properties' => [
            'title' => 'Testing',
        ],
        'sheets' => [$sheet1, $sheet2],
    ]);

    return $this->service->spreadsheets->create($sheetRequest);
}
```

Error:

```
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"0\" at 'spreadsheet.sheets[0].data.row_data': Cannot find field.
```

If I instead change the above line to just the following instead of an array it works.

```
 'sheets' => $sheet1
```

But the spec clearly shows Spreadsheet.sheets as an array: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet

What am I missing here? Does anyone have a good working example of creating a multi-tab spreadsheet using the PHP Sheets API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your showing script (top script), the property of `addSheet` is not included. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. When this is reflected in your 1st script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```php
function addTabs($sheetId, array $tabNames) {
    $requests = [];
    foreach ($tabNames as $index => $tabName) {
        $addSheet = new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request(); // Added
        $request = new AddSheetRequest();
        $props = new SheetProperties();
        $props->setTitle($tabName);
        $props->setIndex($index);
        $request->setProperties($props);
        $addSheet->setAddSheet($request); // Added
        array_push($requests, $addSheet); // Added
    }
    $batchRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    $batchRequest->setRequests($requests);
    try {
        $this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($sheetId, $batchRequest);
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

- By this modification, `requests` is as follows. And, 3 sheets of "A", "B" and "C" are inserted to the Spreadsheet.

  ```json
  [
    {"addSheet":{"properties":{"hidden":null,"index":0,"rightToLeft":null,"sheetId":null,"sheetType":null,"title":"A"}}},
    {"addSheet":{"properties":{"hidden":null,"index":1,"rightToLeft":null,"sheetId":null,"sheetType":null,"title":"B"}}},
    {"addSheet":{"properties":{"hidden":null,"index":2,"rightToLeft":null,"sheetId":null,"sheetType":null,"title":"C"}}}]
  ]
  ```

#### Reference:

- [AddSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest)

Comment: bless , was missing the actual Request middle step there. Was falsly assuming AddSheetRequest was a Request by itself. Thanks @Tanaike!